# Custom firebase reset password email and landing page

Tags: email, firebase, firebase-security, firebase-authentication, firebasesimplelogin

I've been lurking through documentation and am not able to find any notes on possibility to customize email template and password reset page that firebase sends out after this [password reset function.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/resetpassword.html)

Ideally I would also like to use a custom email address like info@mydomain.com when sending out emails. I assume a paid plan might be needed for this, but that's perfectly fine.

Is all or some of above achievable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can customize the email template on any plan, by going to https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/emails

Changing the domain that the mail is sent from (called white listing) is a feature that is available from the Candle plan and up.

Comment: Not anymore true. The new url is: https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/<project-name>/authentication/emails

Comment: fixed the URL on the answer.